# Calculating height in a truncated cone using volume

Tags: geometry

I need to measure the height liquid would come up to in a jug I have. I need to determin how far up the jug the liquid would go (similar to markings on a measuring jug).

Using the volume and lower radius and slant angles to Im looking for a formula I could use. (After translating ml in mmcubed to make it possible)

As an example, if i know the dimensions of the vessel, I would want to know how far up 200ml of liquid would go.

Thanks in advance people!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so call $r$ the radius of the basis, $\theta$ the angle between the vertical axis of the cone and the surface. 
$$\color{red}{h}=\frac{r}{\tan \theta}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{r^3}{\tan^3 \theta}-\frac{3V}{\pi  \tan^2 \theta}}.$$
Of course you have to plug in the measures with the right units, for example: $r$ in $mm$ and $V$ in $mm^3$.

EXAMPLE: you have that $r=45mm$, the graph below for computing $\tan \theta$ remains valid, so $\tan \theta= \frac{6.5}{110}$. Let's say you want $V=200ml=200000mm^3$, the formula gives

$$h=\frac{45\cdot 110}{6.5}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{45^3\cdot 6.5^3}{110^3}-\frac{3\cdot 200000\cdot 110^2}{\pi\cdot 6.5^2}}=\sim 32.8 mm$$

---

EDIT: Since $\tan \theta$ can be difficulte to find, this is an easier way you can calculate it: here is a section of the truncated cone, you have to measure the lenghts $a$ and $b$. Then
$$\tan \theta =\frac{a}{b}$$
[image]

Once you have found $\tan \theta$, it should be easy to compute $\tan^3 \theta$ with a calculator. The quantity $r$ can be measured directly and $V$ is known.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks, I'll give it a go

Comment: Ive tried to work this formula out and cant seem to make sense of the second half of the formula to calculate height from volume, and also the part 'h=x-r/tan...'. I dont seem to be able to calculate tan squared and tan cubed on my calculator which may be a problem. Im getting a figure buts its quite a bit out.

Comment: Please help me firgure this out if you dont mind. Many thanks

Comment: @will See if the edit can help you. Also the only formula you need is the last one, merked in red, which gives you the height given the volume of liquid.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but im still not there. Would it matter if the truncated cone I am working with is the other way up, with the wide part at the bottom rather than the top? Because the height equation I am using still doesnt give me the correct results. I am using a base radius of 45mm and a vertical height of 110m with an upper radius of 38.5mm (if you can envisage the shape with that in mind). Should I be using Cos instead? Etc.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I will get there

Comment: @Will Well, if it's the other way up, i'll have to change the equation!

Comment: @Will I fixed the formula and add an example. hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah that makes perfect sense and the formula youve given brought accurate success! Thank you again for your knowledge and patience

Comment: @mrprottolo I am trying to understand how you arrived at the formula provided.  I assume the starting point is

$V = \frac{1}{3}\pi(r_1^2 + r_1r_2 + r_2^2)h$

I understand to some extent the usage of the tangent to define the height in terms of the radius, but I'm still having trouble trying to solve for h with the above equation as my starting point.  It's been a while since I've done this type of math.  I'm trying to adapt this for an elliptical truncated cone.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the container has shape of a truncated cone .. $r$ is minimum radius at bottom, $R$ at top, the cone has a flare up with $\alpha$, $h$ is height reached.  Using well known relation of truncated cone volume we work up the algebra, defining  $H,a^3$ as

$$ V = \frac{\pi h}{3} ( R^2 + r^2 + R r ), \quad \tan \alpha =  \frac{R-r}{h}  
 ,\quad H = h \tan \alpha,\, \, a^3= \frac{V \tan \alpha}{\pi} \tag1 $$

When $R$ is eliminated to  make a cubic in $H$,

$$ H^3/3 +  H^2 r + H r^2 - a^3 = 0 \tag2 $$

whose only real root is found by *Mathematica* as

$$ H = (3 a^3 +r^3)^{\frac13} - r $$